# Coverting Formula with an If Statement

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am struggling with the logic behind how I would make the second filter an if statement.

Here's the formula.

=sum(filter($C$2:$C$6,$B$2:$B$6=A10,$A$2:$A$6="BUY"))-sum(filter($C$2:$C$6,$B$2:$B$6=A10,$A$2:$A$6="SELL"))

The problem is not all the codes will immediately have a sell therefore there is no sell number to subtract so an error is caused.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Does the answer below work for you? If not, consider adding in the expected result in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `SUMIFS()`

```
=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$6,$B$2:$B$6,A10,$A$2:$A$6,"Buy")-SUMIFS($C$2:$C$6,$B$2:$B$6,A10,$A$2:$A$6,"Sell")
```

[image]